# bitcoin:uri for sending payments to multiple addresses

Tags: address, sending, bip21-uri, sendtoaddress

Lets say I want a donate bitcoin button/QR code to send to multiple recipients in different ratios.

As in send 50% to wallet 1.
Send 25% to wallet 2.
Send 25% to wallet 3.

Is there any way to do this in a single transaction, IE, make a single bitcoin:uri to pay multiple people?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really, but you could put a BIP70 url in the bitcoin uri, or have multiple qr codes.

Comment: I know that BIP70 can have multiple recipients, but for given ratios?

Comment: Your form could ask the intended payment amount, and generate the outputs & signed payment request accordingly?

Comment: I suppose so, but I'd need to build a BIP70 wallet to do this I think